# How to get height of all children elements with JS, Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to get height attribute of all div children.

On this picture you can see a attendence table.
I need to check the height of aech column.
[image]

In my console.log i can retrive each column with this code:

```
mounted() {
     console.log(this.$el.children[1]);
},
```

and I thought if add a method `.clientHeight` I will get each column height.
Unfortunately with this idea I'm get as a result 0.

```
mounted() {
   console.log(this.$el.children[1].clientHeight);
},
```

This is very strange because when I console.log the attributes `console.log(this.$el.children[1].attributes);`

I'm getting this result (yellow marked in picture, **clientHeight: 865**): 
[image]

I have also tried with the `.offsetHeight`(cards, don't have any borders so the result should be the same)

[image]

And this is my HTML code:

```
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-col" ref="department">

        <!-- Department Header -->
        <div class="p-2"
             :style="{'background-color': department.color}"
        >
            {{ department.name }} ({{ persons.length }})
        </div>

        <!-- Department Cards -->
        <div :class="'cards-' + departmentName">
            <card v-for="(person, i) in persons"
                  :key="i"
                  :person="person"
                  :department="department"
            ></card>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: By the time you inspect the element object in the console, its children is already rendered so the height is updated. Try wrapping `Vue.nextTick` in `mounted`

Comment: I'm still getting 0 as result. `this.$nextTick(() => {
                console.log(this.$el.children[1].offsetHeight);
            });` with this

Comment: Try using `setTimeout` with a timeout of 1s. If that works then you know it is a timing issue. The element won't be at the expected size as soon as the component is mounted (are you loading data asynchronously?).

Comment: `mounted() {
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(this.$el.children[1].offsetHeight);
            },1000)
        },` this is working. I'm fettching the data with axios. I replaced the mounted() method with the updated() method and this is also working.